# Is it possible to redirect root email to axigen internal e-mail?

Tags: debian, email, postfix

For a few month I've been using [Axigen](https://www.axigen.com/) webmail as my main e-mail server.

For the last month I was looking for a way of redirecting my root e-mail, as well as my crontab outputs into an internal server, that is handled by Axigen.

Unfortunately because Axigen uses its own dependencies and transport agents, I'm unable to use postfix, as it basically doesn't work alongside Axigen.

I have asked them for a solution on  [their forum](https://www.axigen.com/forum/forum/support-discussion-lists/general-configuration/23001-redirect-root-warning-messages-to-internal-axigen-account), but I have not received any response that might help to solve the problem.

As you could read in the topic, I've managed to get command:

```
$ echo test message | mailx -r misiak -s test username@localhost
```

to work, so I am now able to send myself emails from the console, but it's still not what I'm after.

I'm hoping to get output like this one:

```
bumba is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported. 
bumba@Klocex:~$
```

to arrive to my internal Axigen e-mail account. I am using Debian 8.3 64bit with Kernel 4.4.0. All dependencies up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a `root` alias. In Debian jessie the default MTA is Exim, issue `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config` to change its configuration. Otherwise refer to `man newaliases`.

Comment: /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: exim4-config is broken or not fully installed

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Webadmin -> Domains & Accounts -> Mange Accounts -> edit the account that should receive the root messages -> Account Aliases and add “root” as alias.

Note that the account that will receive the root messages should be in the Primary Domain.

- By default Axigen create the "root" alias for postmaster account.

Comment: Some errors occurred while adding the account alias!